# Jquery UI Tabs Restart Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, gsap

I'm using jquery ui tabs to show different pieces of content on the page. One piece in the content is a few divs that I want animated (fade in) after the tab is clicked. I am using greensock for the animation. So far I am able to get the divs to animate but when another tab is clicked and I go back to the subsequent tab the divs are already there. How to I restart the animation?

Also, is this written correctly? Is there a better efficient way?

Thanks!! noob.

I'm using 'j' as noConflict...

```
j(function() {
        j('#tabs').tabs({ 
            active:0,
            activate: function( event, ui ) {
            myAnimation();

            }

        });

            var tri1 = document.getElementById("tri-one");
            var tri2 = document.getElementById("tri-two");
            var tri3 = document.getElementById("tri-three");
            var tri4 = document.getElementById("tri-four");
            var tri5 = document.getElementById("tri-five");



      function myAnimation() {

            TweenMax.to(tri1, .25, {opacity:1, delay:0});
            TweenMax.to(tri2, .25, {opacity:1, delay:.25});
            TweenMax.to(tri3, .25, {opacity:1, delay:.5});
            TweenMax.to(tri4, .25, {opacity:1, delay:.75});
            TweenMax.to(tri5, .25, {opacity:1, delay:1});
        }
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with greenshock, but the issue might be that you are not resetting the current tab to pinitial state before moving to the next tab. A [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be helpfull...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple really. Basically I have the other tabs just restart the timeline when they are clicked so If i go back to initial tab it will restart. Most importantly the use of the timeline is what was needed.

```
 var tl = new TimelineLite({
            delay: 1
        });
        j(".slide a").click(function() {
            var tr1 = document.getElementById("tri-one");
            var tr2 = document.getElementById("tri-two");
            var tr3 = document.getElementById("tri-three");
            var tr4 = document.getElementById("tri-four");
            var tr5 = document.getElementById("tri-five");

            tl.add(TweenMax.to(tr1, .5, {
                top: "0",
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            }));
            tl.add(TweenMax.to(tr2, .5, {
                top: "0",
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            }));
            tl.add(TweenMax.to(tr3, .5, {
                top: "0",
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            }));
            tl.add(TweenMax.to(tr4, .5, {
                top: "0",
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            }));
            tl.add(TweenMax.to(tr5, .5, {
                top: "0",
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            }));
        });




 j(".info a, .objective a, .chars a, .performance a, .risk a").click(function() {
            tl.restart(true);
        });
```